# Constraintlayout inside scrollview ,always guideline height varies

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

Constraintlayout inside NestedScrollView ,always guideline height varies  .

Guideline Height percentage not works well. it varies depends on recylerview and other view contents.   How to fix this problem , guideline height to fixed inside scrollview

**code**

```
 <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

android:fillViewport="true"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:id="@+id/top_clay"
    android:paddingLeft="0dp"
    android:paddingRight="0dp">

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline_graph"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.35" />

              <TextView

        android:id="@+id/vpager_dsv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/guideline_graph" />


       <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rcv"
        android:layout_width="0dp"

        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"

        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"

        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"


        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/guideline_graph"> 
   </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
 </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: When you say _"Guideline Height percentage not works well"_ what exactly do you mean? Can you post some sort of image to describe what you are seeing?

Comment: problem is constraintlayout inside scrollview, scorllview height depends receylerview contents. so guideline height also varies. any way to fix this?

Comment: hey did you find any solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the {@code Guideline}{@see Guideline} object allows you to create  *
>   Horizontal and Vertical guidelines which are positioned relative to
>   the {@code ConstraintLayout} container.

The above text is copied from the constraint layout documentation. Guideline is positioned based on the container size. So based on the views size inside the constraint layout guideline will vary its position.

I think this behaviour is expected.

Comment: guideline inside scrollview only this problem. anyway to fix it

Comment: I don't think there is a way to fix this.  because in scroll view based on the child height container size varies.

Comment: can you tell , how your UI should look.